# Does the Project Lombok @Data annotation create a constructor of any kind?

Tags: java, constructor, lombok

I have a class with a `@Data` annotation, but I'm not sure whether a constructor with arguments is generated or the only generated constructor is the default (no arguments) one from vanilla Java.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will be generated if no constructor has been defined.

The [Project Lombok @Data page](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) explains:

> @Data is like having implicit @Getter, @Setter, @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode and **@RequiredArgsConstructor** annotations on the class **(except that no constructor will be generated if any explicitly written constructor exists)**.

Comment: How Lombok decides which of (possible) multiple instances to use for constructor argument? when used Data or RequiredArgsConstructor annotations

Answer (score 13):

@Data is only creating a @RequiredArgsConstructor. Lombok documentation site for the [Data annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) and [constructors](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) explains:

> @RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for
> each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final
> fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as
> @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. For those
> fields marked with @NonNull, an explicit null check is also generated.
> The constructor will throw a NullPointerException if any of the
> parameters intended for the fields marked with @NonNull contain null.
> The order of the parameters match the order in which the fields appear
> in your class.

Suppose you have a POJO that uses Lombok @Data annotation:

```
public @Data class Z {
    private String x;
    private String y;
}
```

You can't create the object as `Z z = new Z(x, y);` because there is no arg on your Z class that is "required". It is  creating the constructor with zero parameters because @Data gives you Setters and Getters for your properties and  you can call setX and setY after creating your instance.

You can either make x and y @NonNull or final so they must be passed through the constructor or annotate your class Z with @AllArgsConstructor.