# Which lombok annotation fits best on JPA entity?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, lombok

I use [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and `Hibernate` together.
I'm wondering which lombok annotation should be generally used on entity classes.

First candidate is `@Data` but it generates setters for all non-final fields. Since `id` field is not final I have `setId()` method which I don't want.

The second candidate is `@Value` but then `id` field is marked as final and that's why it has to be manually assigned by an application.

I could also use `@Builder` but it has the same issue as @Data.

To solve problem with `@Data` I can write my own private setter for `id` field to override generated one. But maybe there is a better way? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Add getter and setter annotations to the fields independently. Could use a required args ctor if you require final fields

Comment: You could use settters with restricted access. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299054/479159

Answer (score 0):

i think you're mistaken on what @Data does. @Data combines a bunch of other annotations into one. it doesn't generate code for you. it performs annotations on code you have written.

I highly recommend reading [Does the project lombok data annotation create a constructor of any kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979374/does-the-project-lombok-data-annotation-create-a-constructor-of-any-kind)

This link actually references the appropriate [lombok data page](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't generate code for you"?

Comment: i'm repeating back from your own question: First candidate is @Data **but it generates setters for all non-final fields**. Since id field is not final I have setId() method which I don't want. Annotating a class with Data doesn't generate any getters/setters. if you have written getters/setters it will automatically perform getter/setter annotation processing on them as if you had manually annotated them yourself.

Comment: `@Data`…bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together: iow, `@Data` *generates* all the boilerplate that is normally associated with simple POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) and beans: getters for all fields, setters for all non-final fields, and appropriate toString, equals and hashCode implementations that involve the fields of the class, and a constructor that initializes all final fields, as well as all non-final fields with no initializer that have been marked with `@NonNull`"-- https://projectlombok.org/features/Data